# Export component (compiled) for external websites use (with ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My problem started when **I wanted to use a component as a widget in an external website**.
First of all I created a route with react router to print only that component, so I can use it in an iframe, but the problem was that the component has dropdowns so when they were opened you had to scroll in order to access them.

So I did a research on internet to how to **make a component "widgeable"**, but I could not find anything, or at least anything clear.

And here comes my question, is there a way to export my component, with styles and everything, separately from the whole project to use it as a widget for external websites? Is there an standard way to do it?

Also, is there a way to compile with **webpack a component**? If it is possible, **how can I use it** after being compiled **in an external website?**

In order to give you more information, my component its a form, that form has a dropdown calendar and popups, and with the react-router I've created a route on `/widgets/form` where prints only the form component.

Thanks for reading me!

### Update 1

I would like to avoid adding react to the external website, I do want them to simply add an snippet of JS to their body, like this:

```js
((d, s, u) => {
    const h = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s);
    j.async = true;
    j.src = 'http://localhost:3000/files/widgets/ibb-form.min.js';
    j.onload = () => {
        console.log('Widget: ibblue form loaded!');
        start({ url: u });
    };
    h.parentNode.insertBefore(j, h);
})(document, 'script', 'http://localhost:3000/widgets/form');

function start({ url }) {
    new window.IBBForm({ url });
}
```

and the JS that I use in the script that snippet adds it's the following one:

```js
(() => {
    const IBBForm = class {
        constructor({ id, url }) {
            this._elementID = id || '#ibblue_form';
            this._target = document.querySelector(this._elementID);

            if (!url) throw new Error('No URL specified');
            this._url = url;

            this._iframe = this._createIframe();
            this._target.append(this._iframe);
        }

        _createIframe() {
            const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.id = 'ibblue_form_iframe_' + new Date().getTime();
            iframe.src = this._url;
            iframe.style =
                'width: 100%; height: 600px; border: medium none; background-color: transparent; display: initial;';
            iframe.allowTransparency = 'true';
            return iframe;
        }
    };

    window['IBBForm'] = IBBForm;
})();
```

### Update 2

I edited the script downloaded to the following one:

```js
import BookingSearch from './../../src/components/sections/BookingSearch';

(() => {
    const IBBForm = class {
        constructor({ id, url }) {
            this._elementID = id || '#ibblue_form';
            this._target = document.querySelector(this._elementID);

            if (!url) throw new Error('No URL specified');
            this._url = url;

            this._addRequirements().then(() => {
                this._element = this._createForm();
            });
        }

        async _addRequirements() {
            await this._addScript('https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js');
            await this._addScript('https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js');
        }

        async _addScript(url) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const h = document.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    j = document.createElement(s);
                j.async = true;
                j.type = 'module';
                j.src = url;
                j.crossorigin = '';
                j.onload = resolve();
                h.parentNode.insertBefore(j, h);
            });
        }

        _createForm() {
            return ReactDOM.render(<BookingSearch widget={true} dataTheme={{}} />, this._target);
        }
    };

    window['IBBForm'] = IBBForm;
})();
```

When I execute it, console throws some errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.IBBForm is not a constructor
```

Comment: what do you mean by widget exactly? how does the developer or whomever "attach" your component? through code?

Comment: the general answer is that you can export just the single component then the developer can `ReactDOM.render(<YourWidget />, '#foo')`

Comment: What I do not want to add react into the external website? I want it like a simple snipet of code, I'll attach an example.

Comment: well then you would probably need to export a function that calls `ReactDOM.render` so that the consumer can call your function which invokes react.

Comment: the same principle applies if you make a jQuery widget -- but again it kind of depends on what your consumer is expecting

Comment: Does It make it more clear with the last update what I tried to reach?

Comment: It does I think - as long as your script provides a function that you can call that takes an element to attach your react root node to you should be fine

Comment: So in the script I add with the snippet, if I import React from there and call the `ReactDOM.render` from there, should be fine, isn't it?

Comment: don't see why not - as long as the snippet is the compiled code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240145/discussion-between-marc-j-cabrer-and-azium).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating an iframe with the route to the "widget" (`/widgets/form`) solves pretty much the problem, the idea was to serve a built js of the react widget but that was not possible.

I could also print the dom of the widget into the website, but I rejected that option for some internal reasons.

Thanks to all you commented and helped me to reach that decision!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a Component Library by rollup.

See this tutorial to make an example: https://blog.harveydelaney.com/creating-your-own-react-component-library/

After publishing your Component Library, you can install and use it in external projects.

Comment: I don't think you understand the OP correctly. The target environment is not necessarily a react a website

Comment: The consumer only have to import a simple snippet of code, I just updated the post. Thanks btw!